# correct use of processName LogRecord attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm using the standard Python way of logging as documented in various places including tutorials. 
All my package modules have the following logger definition, and then I use it throughout the module

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I'm using `SysLogHandler` and my loggers are hierarchical throughout the package. I have a `systemd.service` file that runs a script as a daemon process. I configure the parent logger (direct child of `root` logger) with the appropriate filters+handlers etc. in this script.

I used a pretty basic format string

```
'%(name)s[%(process)d]: %(levelname)-10s %(message)s'
```

This works just fine, but I would like to use `processName` instead.

```
'%(processName)s[%(process)d]: %(levelname)-10s %(message)s'
```

I'm expecting this would make my log records more uniform in syslog and make the association of log entries to the process much more apparent (process name and not just the pid).

I looked at other SO answers and reviewed the `logging`, `logging.handlers` library
pages and the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging-cookbook.html) as well. None of them seem to hint at how this `processName` can be used.

All I want is to see my script name instead of the value returned by `mutliprocess.current_process().name`, which is always `MainProcess`

Is there a document I'm missing? Or am I going about it the wrong way..?

Python version: 3.5.X
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 and Centos7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has a list of [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes), which is what the formatter is accessing for this. You probably want to use `%{filename}s`. If you need anything that is not available by default you can pass additional attributes by using the `extra` kwarg when creating the log.